# HTC ONE hung and can not restart the phone

Tags: htc-one, hard-reset

I have a HTC ONE. While using the phone it got hung. And when i tried to use the power button the Display as well got switched off.

Now When i try to hold the Power button for ten seconds and try to hard restart its of no use. When i connect the phone to a pc via USB i get the device detected sound on windows but HTC One doesnt show its mass storage.

Any way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 10):

As per XDA [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2247847) you can perform force restart by doing this.

```
To reboot the phone without ADB, just hold down the Vol Up and power button for 9 seconds, the phone should shut down.
```

If this doesn't power down the phone, you can try this. Lot of people has reported success in this method for most of the HTC phones.

```
Put your phone under a bright light then hold power+volume down.
```

If both of them fails, you have to wait till the battery die and let it charge and power on the phone normally.

Hope this helps you. Good luck.

Comment: i gave it to the service center waiting for them to get back to me :(

Comment: Looks like a hardware issue.

Answer (score 3):

As odd as it may sound, I found a solution in the net and it worked for me twice already !!
Put the phone in a bright light, strong bulb or direct sun, and do a hard reset!!

Worked twice for me.

Comment: It worked for me too, just using another phone lighter and pointing directly to front camera and sensors.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem with my HTC One M7, but the vol down or vol up with power button didn't force it to reboot.

I was messing around with the phone and a call came in.  I was able to answer the call and after the call my phone went back to normal!  So I'd suggest trying to call the phone from another phone.